# Recognize L-Shape in a 4x4 Matrix

Tags: java, matrix, android-studio

I'm trying to make a board game, there the player has to press four buttons to make the L. It can be mirrored or rotated, it just has to be an L.
But if the player press four buttons and make another shape, like a line or a Z, the system must recognize it and alert the player.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting goal. What have you done so far to try to achieve this goal? Where specifically did you run into a snag that we can help you with?

Comment: The problem is after the player pressed the 4 buttons. The system will receive a boolean matrix with 'true' being the buttons pressed, the snag is how the program will recognize those positions as an L (sorry if it's too confusing)

Comment: Again, that sounds like a cool goal. But this isn't a code-writing service where you tell us your goal and we write the code for you. We can help you solve a specific problem you've run into when trying to achieve this goal, but currently your question doesn't show us any of your code or approach so far. So we can't tell what part of this you need help with. Please edit your question to show how you've tried to solve the problem so far and where you're stuck.